# How to calculate an aggregated sum of a value after converted times from other US time zones using UTC_OFFSETS

Tags: sql, oracle

I am super lost. I am trying to create a sum of all the values in a certain day after converting all time zones to PST (Pacific Standard Time ; UTC_OFFSET = 4 during non DST, UTC_OFFSET = 5 during dst)  I was thinking of first converting all time zones (based on the UTC_OFFSET and the  date/timestamp, then converting the date/timestamp to a date , and just summing/grouping by the date. I am having a hard time behind how i will handle the inevitable DST (especially since it happens on a different date every year). I am also not 100% sure if my mathematical formula to derive the PST is correct from other US timezones using the value for UTC_OFFSET. I am trying to sum all of the values from a certain PST day regardless of where the data is being pulled from.

Below are the the utc offset to convert from UTC to the speecified time zone

```
UTC_OFFSET:
4 (EST during DST)
5 (Central Time during DST, EST during NON DST)
6 (Mountain Time during DST, Central time during NON DST)
7 (PST during DST, Mountain Time during non dst)
8 (Pst during non dst)
```

Below is some sample data that I have:

```
During Daylight Savings Time
    Value        HR                                 UTC
    777          18-FEB-19 05.00.00.000000000 AM    4
    888          18-FEB-19 06.00.00.000000000 AM    5
      1          18-FEB-19 07.00.00.000000000 AM    6
      5          18-FEB-19 08.00.00.000000000 AM    7

During Non-Daylight Savings Time
Value        HR                                 UTC
777          18-FEB-19 05.00.00.000000000 AM    5
888          18-FEB-19 06.00.00.000000000 AM    6
  1          18-FEB-19 07.00.00.000000000 AM    7
  5          18-FEB-19 08.00.00.000000000 AM    8
```

Expected Output (for both):

```
 Sum(Value)      Date
 1671            Feb-18-19
```

Below is what I have tried:

```
select to_Char(HR - ((UTC_OFFSET - 2)/ 24), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as converted_pacific_time 
     , sum(value_tx)
from value
group by to_Char(HR - ((UTC_OFFSET - 2)/ 24), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```
FROM_TZ(HR, UTC_OFFSET||':00')
```

Then pick an arbitrary time zone and group by that:

```
select sum(value_tx), FROM_TZ(HR, UTC_OFFSET||':00') at time zone 'UTC'
from value
group by FROM_TZ(HR, UTC_OFFSET||':00') at time zone 'UTC';
```

or for UTC:

```
select sum(value_tx), SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(HR, UTC_OFFSET||':00'))
from value
group by SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(HR, UTC_OFFSET||':00'));
```